# Curious Badge: What is a "well-received question"?

Tags: discussion, badges

Is the Curious badge new? What constitutes a "well-received question"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0.

See [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/163749) for more details on the new badges.